# Anger plus Hatred Combined

Tags: single-word-requests

Considering:

> 1. I am angry with him.
> 2. I hate him.

Is the second just a stronger feeling than the first?

I am tempted to say "no"—one may hate another because he is jealous of him (or whatever). *If the second has other connotations other than being a stronger version of the first*, is there a word that would convey "anger" and "hatred" combined?

Comment: You can be angry with somebody you love. But short of mixing expressions (or being imprecise), you can't hate somebody who you love.

Answer (score 1):

The first indicates a particular problem with him.  The second indicates a general strong feeling against him.